# Convection through a bigger window

Tags: fluid-dynamics, convection

So I am currently doing an investigation and the location that I chose for the project is a rainforest. So I was wondering if the window is bigger in my tree house will it affect the way convection works? like will there be more cool air or less cool air? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to have two windows. Because if you have a single window of any size, Air will not enter if it is closely packed.[image]
       But still there is a chance of air entering in by only a single big window. If it is cool air, obviously it enters from bottom side. The pressure inside the room is increased, hence the air would leave. As hot air is lighter than cool air, hot air would leave from top of window.[image]

```
   Construct two windows in 

       1. Opposite direction.
            You would get maximum air flow,if flow is perpendicular to windows. If along the windows you would not get air inside.

       2. Windows perpendicularly.
            You would get moderate flow even wind is flowing in any direction.
```